# Trying to extract elements from XML and place into an Array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I've created a simple XML document that will hold information on numerous cities.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<config>
    <city>
        <id>London</id>
    </city>
    <city>
        <id>New York</id>
    </city>
</config>
```

I'm trying to extract the city  elements and place them into an array.  I have the following so far and the output is simply `Array` when I call the function.

```
<?php
$configFile = 'cityConfig.xml';

function getCityConfig($configFile) {

    $xml = new SimpleXmlElement(file_get_contents("cityConfig.xml"));

    $cities = array();

    $cityId = $xml->city[0]->id;
    array_push($cities, $cityId);
    $cityId = $xml->city[1]->id;
    array_push($cities, $cityId);

    //var_dump($cities); 

    return $cities;
}

//print_r(getCityConfig($configFile)); 
echo getCityConfig($configFile); 

?>
```

`var_dump` suggests that values are being added into the array.

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { [0]=> string(6) "London" } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) { [0]=> string(8) "New York" } } Array
```

I'm trying to achieve something along these lines.

```
$cities = array(
   'London',
    'New York',
    'Paris'
);
```

The array indexes are called in my index.php to display content.

```
$pageIntroductionContent = 'The following page brings twin cities together. Here you will find background information on  ' . $cities[0] . ', ' . $cities[1] . ' and ' . $cities[2] . '.';
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that in **SimpleXMLElement** object, all the data is represented as an object, including attributes (as your `var_dump` suggests, in fact). So, you can get strings by casting these object, because they implement a `_toString()` method I think. Try:

```
$cityId = (string) $xml->city[0]->id;
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one out. Any ideas where I'm going wrong regarding printing out the contents on the array?

Comment: Your code is ok, you just need to cast strings as I said. If you are talking about `echo getCityConfig(..)`, in PHP you cannot print out an array this way. You have to use `print_r` or `var_dump`. In fact, array are not strings, so it has no sense to output a whole array.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  The last problem is access to the array indexes in my index.php script, the `$pageIntroductionContent`. I get undefined function when trying to call `index 0` and `Warning: file_get_contents(cityConfig.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream` if I `require cityConfig.php`

Comment: So, you have a problem accessing `cityConfig.xml`. Re-check file paths.